# Библиотеки для C++ для проверки форматов файлов: doc docx xls xlsx pdf

Tags: c++

Подскажите библиотеки на C++ (желательно хорошо переносимые) для проверки файлов на принадлежность к формату doc docx xls xlsx pdf. Ну и конечно желательно бесплатные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть linux'овая утилита [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file). Она делает примерную оценку к какому типу принадлежит файл. Можете попытаться найти ее исходный код и проанализировать.

В остальном же - проще взять и подключить библиотеки MS Office и OpenOffice и анализ делать их средствами.

PS: PDF легко определить по сигнатуре %PDF в начале файла - см. [спецификацию формата](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf.html).